# How to determine whether the COM port is virtual or not?

Tags: delphi, serial-port, delphi-7

In order to accept only non-virtual COM ports, how to determine whether the COM port is virtual or not in Delphi ?

Answer (score 1):

It is made virtual by a device driver.  You can't get to it from a user-mode program.  Running a WMI query for Win32_SerialPort leaves a breadcrumb, Description property, nothing that ever repeats well on a different machine with different hardware.  The point of virtualizing it is to make it look as much as a hardware port as possible, a good driver makes it impossible to tell the difference.

You can otherwise just plain assume "yes".  It's pretty rare to find a PCI-E card with real UARTs these days, the convenience of pluggable USB is just too great.  And ridiculously dirt-cheap, Amazon lists a USB emulator for $3.21.  Most of all, do avoid having to know.